# Issues web scraping text from grid table values using Beautiful Soup for Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get real time stock market book orders from the website https://markets.cboe.com/us/equities/market_statistics/book_viewer/, however when I try and get the actual numbers by looping through the td children, my python list is filled with the side headers 'ASK' and 'BID' and then instead of the desired data my list is filled with the space ('\xa0') placeholder from HTML. Is there an error that I am making or is the website not allowing me to parse this info. SIDENOTE: I am able to grab other info from this site like news links, headings, and titles. Below is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

url = "https://markets.cboe.com/us/equities/market_statistics/book_viewer/"
uClient = uReq(url)
html_page = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
soup1 = soup.find('div', class_="app book-viewer")
main = soup1.find('table', class_='bats-table book-viewer-data-table')
all_tr = main.find_all('tr', class_='book-viewer-data-row')

for tr in all_tr:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)

That runs with the output:
['Asks', '\xa0', '', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0']
['\xa0', '', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0']
['\xa0', '', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0']
['\xa0', '', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0']
['\n\n', '\xa0', '', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0']
['\n\n', 'Bids', '\xa0', '', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0']
['\xa0', '', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0']
['\xa0', '', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0']
['\xa0', '', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0']
['\xa0', '', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0']
```

-> this is the correct number of rows/columns for the data table, I am just unable to actually get useable information

Comment: sorry about the 'That runs with the output' that is not actually in my running code

Answer (score 1):

The data you see is loaded from other URL. To get the data you can use `requests`/`json` libary:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://markets.cboe.com/json/bzx/book/SLV'
headers = {'Referer': 'https://markets.cboe.com/us/equities/market_statistics/book_viewer/'}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some data to screen:
for t in data['data']['trades']:
    print('{:<10} {:<5} {}'.format(*t))
```

Prints:

```
17:53:36   100   26.28
17:47:06   100   26.29
17:36:46   100   26.28
17:16:37   100   26.31
17:12:41   100   26.31
17:12:20   100   26.29
16:51:33   4800  26.3
16:44:32   100   26.22
16:37:12   5     26.25
16:37:10   100   26.25
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I will be using it in my code, I appreciate all of you!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your script. However, your approach would not work on such data that is updated in real-time.

What BeautifulSoup does is that it parses the XML content of a certain page which is everything that is loaded from the server with the first GET request. So XML content contains only static or semi-static contents.
On the contrary, stock market prices are fetched with an API either with a socket that changes whenever the source price changes or by a corn job that calls the API on intervals.

Either way, you need to call the source API directly yourself that I believe there is a handful of open-APIs with JSON output for stock market prices. If you couldn't find an original API for some data that you see rendered on a website, you could use the inspect feature of your browser and find the root of a request in the Network section.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: I see, my original approach was to use an API, but all of them are a bit pricey. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check this [article](https://medium.com/@andy.m9627/the-ultimate-guide-to-stock-market-apis-for-2020-1de6f55adbb) out. It should give you resources and implementation ideas to achieve your goal.